# non-zero value of 2 numbers with a return exit code in shell

Tags: shell, unix, aix

So here's my situation.

I want to be able to exit RC/RC1 which has a non-zero value. When the below code is executed if RC is 0 RC1 is returned with a non-zero exit code(best case scenario) if RC is non-zero and RC1 is also non-zero i will miss exit code of RC1(meaning i will not be able to use RC1's exit code). How can i send the right exit code? In essence i would like to email the non-zero variable

```
if [ $RC -ne 0 ] || [ $RC1 -ne 0 ]; then
        if [ $RC -ne 0 ]; then
        exit $RC
        else
        exit $RC1
fi
```

Comment: You wrote `RC is non-zero and RC1 is also non-zero`. Your code gives precedence of RC when it's non-zero to return this value and not RC1. You can't return more than 1 exit code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to return two exit codes at the same time? I guess that, when driving a car, you also want to sit on the front seat and on the back seat at the same time. You *can* do it, but you need a special car for this. Here are two ideas for making such a car:

- If you know that in this context each exit code must be a 1-digit number, you could return something like `$((RC*10+RC2))` - I'm using bash/zsh syntax here, as you didn't say which shell you are using. If necessary, you have to adapt this to your shell.
- You could adapt the interface of your script, by printing something like "$RC1 $RC2" to stderr if at least one of them is non-zero, i.e.:

  ```
  if [ $RC -ne 0 ] || [ $RC1 -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "$RC $RC1" 1>&2
    exit 1
  else
    exit 0
  fi
  ```

In both cases, the calling process has to take apart the combined exit code to get back the original ones.